# Apache 2.4 too many redirects with www to non-www and http to https

Tags: apache, virtualhost

httpd.conf:

```
Include conf.d/ports.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

conf.d/ports.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

sites-enabled/example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.com.certificate.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.com.key.key

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com.access.log combined

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/example.com/public_html/$1
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

... but it just gives me "too many redirects" for any combination (www, non-www, http or https).

Comment: Your `ServerName www.example.com` *and* `ServerAlias example.com` directives should be inside both VirtualHost port 80 and 443.

Comment: @Nic3500 Tried that already, no effect.

Comment: Is there any other VirtualHost on ports 80 or 443 in the *.conf files?  If so, could you try with only the example.com.conf?  There could be some other redirect rules in the other conf files?

Comment: @Nic3500 No other conf files

Comment: If you do `https://www.example.com` you will end up in the :443 VirtualHost.  There is no redirect directive in there, how can you be redirected?  Unless your fcgi... on port 9000 sends you back to `https://www.example.com` again?